# Application Insights tracking only failed ASP.NET MVC Web API requests

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a ASP.NET Web API controller that provides a saveAndNew operation.

This class is derived from System.Web.Http.ApiController as expected.

Application Insights is correctly configured using version 2.1.0 of the SDK and the default settings in ApplicationInsights.config.

If a request to **the mentioned operation fails** - for example with status code 400 - **the request is recorded correctly** in App Insights.

The problem is that **if the operation SUCCEEDS** (status code 200) **nothing is recorded in Application Insights**.

I've used Fiddler to see if the request is made to the App Insights track service and it is not. So the problem is not in the configuration of Application Insights on the Azure portal.

I can't figure out what is preventing ALL requests to my Web API controllers operations from being recorded.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try removing/commenting out [`TransferRequestHandler`](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/v2.1.0/Src/Web/Web.Nuget/Resources/ApplicationInsights.config.install.xdt#L29) in ApplicationInsights.config file.

GitHub issue *"REST API app can have all requests filtered out"* [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/175) states that: "commenting out the one line in the ApplicationInsights.config caused successful requests to start getting logged. Web API 2 project.

```
<!--<Add>System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler</Add>-->
```