# Application Insights: only request failures appearing

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-application-insights

I have a ASP.NET Web API 2 project deployed to an Azure App Service. I have configured App Insights by right-clicking on my web project and going to Add > Application Insights Telemetry which installed the latest version of the SDK. I set the instrumentation key on Startup.

When I look in the Azure Portal and see what is being logged I realise that only failed requests are appearing (5xx and 4xx status codes). Looking at the AI documentation from Microsoft, it suggests that I should be seeing all requests being logged here. When I look on the Application map I see 100% failures for my server application. When I go to Live Metrics Stream and hit the API, I can see dependencies being logged as shown on the relevant graph but the requests are flat lining. What is AI struggling with here, how come only the failed requests are appearing? I don't have any sampling turned on apart from the default, so far I have configured everything out of the box. I have exceptions logging also which seems to work. Has anyone had any problems getting AI to work specifically with Web API and requests?

I am using Owin and targeting .NET Framework version 4.6.1.

Comment: As you said that `When I look on the Application map I see 100% failures for my server application`, could you show us some detailed exceptions? Do your web application could work without using the AI?

Comment: @BruceChen they are application errors, bad requests, unauthorised requests. The point is, these errors are being logged but successful 200 responses are not. Not sure what you mean exactly, are you suggesting use something else instead? This question is specifically about Application Insights. I'm not looking for suggestions of alternatives as a solution to this problem though, thanks.

Comment: I created my web API and installed the AI as you described, and I could retrieve all the logs. Have you tried to [Using the Trace API directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-trace-logs#using-the-trace-api-directly) within your code to narrow this issue? Also, you could try to set up AI at runtime, more details you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now).

Comment: @BruceChen Hi, how did you create your Web API, is it targeting the same framework version? How did you deploy to Azure, from VS via Web Deploy? Did you create the instance of AI first? Thanks, but the Trace API is for logging traces not requests. I'm not sure how I could narrow the issue with this as I'd need to create custom middleware. I don't need to instrument the application at runtime as I've already deployed the app with the Application Insights SDK installed? Interestingly, the App Service is picking up 200 requests under Metrics but Application Insights is not... most frustrating.

Comment: I found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971641/application-insights-tracking-only-failed-asp-net-mvc-web-api-requests?rq=1 and tried the solution there and it has now started logging the other requests. Flagging this as duplicate